# How to interpret/compare R2 score(s)?

Tags: r-squared, model-comparison

I know that an R² score of 1 is a perfect fit of the model to the truth, a 0 is an constant output regardless of the input, and that negative values are possible when the output varies, but there is no correlation with the input. (At least that's how I understand it?)

But... how do I interpret these values? Or: how do I compare two values with eachother? 
Comparing 0.8 with 0.9 is obvious: the 2nd value is better than the first. But how to compare low values with negative values?

For example, I have this graph:

[image: Prediction vs truth]

The green curve is the measurement, while the blue curve is the prediction. I'd expect the R² score to be very low, because it clearly isn't a good prediction, but... turns out, it is a negative value: -1.19.

How do I know which is better? A score of 0.19? Or a score of -1.19?

considering a score of 0 means a constant (wrong) value, then -1.19 must be better than 0?

Follow-up Question: I'm working on a project where I compare several techniques by their R²-score. I was planning on drawing a bar-plot with all the results as an overview. How would I do this, when -1.19 is better than 0, but 1 is best?

Follow-up Question 2: Maybe I'm using the wrong type of metric for this kind of comparison? Am I?

Comment: I use R-squared (R2) to tell me how much of the data variance is explained by the regression model, calculated as "R2 = 1.0 - (regression_error_variance / dependent_data_variance)" . If the model fits perfectly through all data points and that means all errors are zero, and the  error variance is zero because all errors are equal value - in a perfect fit  R2 = 1.0 - (0.0 / dependent_data_variance) or just 1.0. Using this calculation, R-squared can only be negative if the error variance is *greater* than the dependent data variance which would tell me that the model is horribly bad.

Comment: Also relevant: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13314/is-r2-useful-or-dangerous and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/414349/is-my-model-any-good-based-on-the-diagnostic-metric-r2-auc-accuracy-e

Comment: Not sure why I got an alert just now, but I now see that this question was closed as a duplicate 3 years ago. I however think this is erroneous. 
The linked question asked when R2 becomes negative. The answers give a mathematical explanation.
This question however asks how a positive and a negative R2 can be compared with each other to find the best fit. It's a totally different question imho.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an image where different R2 Scores are compared:

[image: Compare R2]

The blue dots are the ground truth data. Each line has a different prediction. As expected, note that the orange line has an R2 score very close to 1. Also note that the red fits very badly the dataset and has a negative score of -1.55. The intuition here is that a negative score means that the model is in the opposite trend of the data.

In case you are familiar with Python, feel free to play with the [source code](https://gist.github.com/WittmannF/02060b45ce3ec9239898a5b91df2564e).

Comment: I don't get why you got downvoted. Even though this question is very old, it is exactly what I was asking back then.

Comment: Note to downvoters: This answer is meant for those coming from Google since it is being ranked as the first result when searching for 'comparing r2 scores'